# How can I prevent my raspberry pi from going to sleep (not on xserver)

Tags: raspberry-pi

Ex. I like to leave up pihole -t on my display, but after 10 minutes the screen connected through HDMI goes blank, but remains on, so that it doesn't have to rewake it.

I've used `sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"` but that only works for that boot session, as soon as a reboot command is sent this is no longer effective and would have to be run at every startup.

Setting `xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` also doesn't do anything (as I assumed).

I do use ssh quite a lot, but this case I find it easier to have the monitor directly connected to the pi.